# Gradle Kotlin DSL multi project build with Java Modules

Tags: gradle, kotlin, java-module, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm creating a new project (using IntelliJ IDEA) that will be using:

- Gradle as the build system
- Kotlin DSL for build scripts
- Java 9 modules for "organisation"
- Kotlin as the primary language

I'm having problems setting up Gradle to properly build my project. Most examples I've found are for Groovy and not Kotlin DSL, and most only cover some of the features I want, but not all.

Right now I have two modules, *core* and *lib*, where the *core* module requires the *lib* module. My gradle build scripts are:

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    base
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.41" apply false
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
            inputs.property("moduleName", extra["moduleName"])
            options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf("--module-path", classpath.asPath))
            classpath = files()
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**core/build.gradle.kts**

```
extra.set("moduleName", "myproject.core")

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
    compile(project(":networking"))
}
```

**lib/build.gradle.kts**

```
extra.set("moduleName", "myproject.lib")

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib"))
}
```

Doing this, configuration fails with:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':core'.
>
> Cannot get property 'moduleName' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

If I remove the `inputs.property()` line the configuration succeeds, but the *core* compilation fails (*lib* compiles successfully) with :

> Task :core:compileKotlin
>
> e: Module myproject.lib cannot be found in the module graph

I assume the issue is is my root `build.gradle.kts`, but I cannot figure out how to make it work. Googling around, Kotlin DSL for Gradle is somewhat new and not as widely used, and documentation is pretty scarce.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Naturally after posting the question I found the solution. There exists a Gradle plugin that does exactly what's needed in this situation, with a KotlinDSL example: https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin/tree/master/test-project-kotlin

Using the plugin, all I needed to do is change the root `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    base
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.41" apply false
    id("org.javamodularity.moduleplugin") version "1.5.0" apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.javamodularity.moduleplugin")

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Note: Make sure that your module-info.java file is in the `java` src folder, and not in the `kotlin` src folder, otherwise the plugin will not detect the module.**